# Is it semantic to include aria-invalid on a checkbox or dropdown?

Tags: html, accessibility

If I have a checkbox like this:

`<input type="checkbox" required aria-invalid>`

Is this semantically valid / Does it make sense to place the `aria-invalid` attribute?

The way I interpret it is that if it's `required`, then it would be invalid/makes any form that it's in invalid if it's not selected (e.g. Terms & Conditions checkbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is semantically correct in the given example of a checkbox that is required for things like T&Cs.

Make sure you have a valid and correctly linked error message on submit such as "you must accept the terms and conditions to continue" if it is still not checked.

**Make sure you update the `aria-invalid` as soon as the checkbox is ticked or this may cause confusion**

You mentioned a drop-down in your question, that is an entirely different thing and would depend on your use case (but generally if this is a "you must select an option" then using `aria-invalid` is correct until a value is selected), if you want to add an example of what you are thinking we can guide you better.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to detail the use case for the dropdown but the situation you've described is exactly my use case as the dropdown is a required form input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly correct to have aria-invalid for a checkbox, But required attribute should normally suffice. You don't need aria-invalid in this case.

It is automatically considered invalid if the checkbox isn't checked, and the invalid indication is cleared as soon as you check the box.
No need to use aria-invalid if this is exactly the behavior you expect.